# how to make a program remind me in a specific time everyday in python?

Tags: python, notifications, schedule, reminders

I tried to make a program that reminds me of a specific time everyday with a notification, there is no errors, but the code doesn't work and I really don't know how to solve this.
This is the code:

```
import schedule
from plyer import notification


def send_notification():
    notification.notify(
    title = "Take A Break!!!",
    timeout = 10
    )
while True:
    schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(send_notification)
```

Comment: Why the while true loop?

Comment: `from phone import alarm_clock`...

Comment: Take a look at crontabs if you're using a UNIX-like OS

Comment: does notification work on its own?

Comment: khelwood because if I run the program without it, it will finish if the given time isn't the current time

Comment: jvrn3 Sorry, I don't use this OS.

Comment: jsotola it's not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#example), you using the package wrong:

```py
import schedule
import time
from plyer import notification


def send_notification():
    notification.notify(
    title = "Take A Break!!!",
    timeout = 10
    )

schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(send_notification)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working!!